# Calculate bootstrap classes depending on container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a container with class of six columns (e.g.). I want elements inside that container to calculate their widths like container size is 12 columns. So whatever size container is, elements inside see him as 12 columns and having that in  mind calculate their widths in proportion to container.

I didn't know better to explain. Hope that somebody understands what i need

@Skelly: Here is the code (e.g.)

```
<div class="container span6">     
    <div class="element span3"></div>
    <div class="element span9"></div>
</div>
```

You see my point? I want to automatically calculate widths of elements having in mind that for them container is always 12 columns even if it says 6

Comment: Can you clarify, and/or post the code you're using?

Comment: Posted code into question now

Comment: the container/row will always be 12 unless you're talking about nested grids.

Comment: yes but i need to CALCULATE the widths of elements in container. Above code is just example of what i want to accomplish after calculation

Comment: Any chance you can use Bootstrap 3 instead. It would "automatically" scale up to 12 for you: http://www.bootply.com/122470

Comment: Nope. i must use developed logic for re sizing elements and after that adding classes to them. I would just need the logic of calculation

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">col-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">col-2</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">col-3</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">col-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">col-5</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">col-6</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">col-7</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">col-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">col-9</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">col-10</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">col-11</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">col-12</div>
</div>
```

Above code gives you 12 columns of equal size according to the container size.

Use **CTRL+SHIFT+M** in mozilla firefox and change resolution and check. If possible give color for each divs and could see the things better.

Hope this clarifies your question.

More info: http://getbootstrap.com/css/ with examples.